# how to count # of records depending on two conditions in excel

Tags: excel

in aother words: if cell contains text and another cell contains another text then count the record

let say we have some data in a table1 in sheet1

C1      C2        C3        C4

**ST**       1         2         **3**

SR       3         2          1

CE       6         4           3

**ST**       1        9         **3**

**ST**       1         4         **3**

I want to save the count of records having ST in C1 and 3 in C4 
and save it in a cell.
thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific... Save in what cell? Just the Counts of ST and just the counts of 3, or the counts of records having only col 1 with ST AND col 4 with 3? What about 3 in row 2 col 2?

Comment: Look into `COUNTIF()`. If you can be more specific about your expected result, then you may get more help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in an unused cell,

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "ST", D:D, 3)
```

[image]